# Processing json output as array

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I've created a search while typing method using this demo:
    https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/
But now i'm stuck with processing the results.
I want to receive back a list of data (that works) but also per dataline an id which should not be visible, but
which i can use as post data in the submit.
I probably have to change the json array and put the id in it, but i then i don't know how to seperate the data in the post form and use the id as hidden id.
To clearify my example: I have a table with strings (can be duplicate) and unique number id's.
I want the list to contain the strings and i want to submit with just the id.

I also found a lot of simular projects all looking a bit different, i especially like the looks of this one, creating a hovering results box and not changing anything to my form.

Answer (score 2):

use [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  on  result

json_decode($json)  will give  you object in return

json_decode($json,true)   vill give you  array in  return

Comment: Tnx for your reply Michal, I'm not sure where you mean i should use that function. As i understand (and i'm only a beginner for ajax/json) the handling of the json return is done in the typeahead.min.js as java so i cannot use a php function in there. But am i correct as i understand that since the query result is being encoded in json i can add extra values to that array and i should decode it then in the js and make it only display my values? If so how then can i also get the id in php? Well at least i have something to look into now, thanks! But more (specific) help would be appriciated.